# Kaplansky for Projections

Tags: von-neumann-algebras

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, and $A$ a $C^*$-subalgebra of $B(H)$ (the bounded operators on $H$). Let $B$ be the strong-operator closure of $A$, so that in particular, $B$ is a von-Neumann-algebra.

According to the Kaplansky-Theorem:

The … in the unit ball of $A$ is s-o dense in the … in unit ball of $B$, where … is:

- unitaries
- self adjoints

Does it hold, that $\operatorname{Proj}(A)$ is strongly dense in $\operatorname{Proj}(B)$ (or even weakly dense).

*I.e.* does the Kaplansky-Theorem hold for projections? (Or a weaker version of it.)

If not, why not?

Answer (score 1):

No.  E.g., let $A=C[0,1]$ acting as multiplication operators on $L^2[0,1]$.  The only projections in $A$ are $0$ and $1$.  The strong closure contains multiplications by the characteristic functions of all measurable subsets of $[0,1]$.

More generally, infinite-dimensional C*-algebras need not have projections, while von Neumann algebras are spanned by projections.

Comment: What about if $B$ is, say, the hyperfinite $II_1$ factor?

Comment: (See edit: I meant B.)

Comment: I don't know if it is true in that case.

Comment: Could one obtain a bridge result, say: Kaplansky holds for partial isometries? That would also be useful to me.

Comment: RS8: In the example in my answer, the set of partial isometries in $A$ is not strongly dense in the set of partial isometries in $B$. I don't know about weak density.

Comment: @RS8: I don't think you can do this in the case of the hyperfinite factor either. In particular if you find a icc torsion-free amenable group (take for example the wreath product $\mathbb{Z}\wr\mathbb{Z}$), then I would think that the reduced group $C^*$-algebra (which is dense in the hyperfinite $II_1)$ has no non trivial projections (and thus no non-unitary partial isometries).